# Unable to resolve dependencies: geo-distance

Tags: ruby, rubygems

When install this gem:
https://rubygems.org/gems/geo-distance

via ruby gems, I get:

```
Unable to resolve dependencies: geo-distance requires geo_units (~> 0.2.4.1); geo_calc requires sugar-high (>= 0.6.0), geo_units (>= 0.3.1.1)
```

I've tried installing that specific version but still geting the same issue. Can someone recomment an alternative and/or how to fix this problem?
Thanks

Comment: Do you use Bundler? If so, can you show us its content?

Comment: Not using bundler @basgys

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe you should consider using Bundler.

**Installation**

```
gem install bundler
```

**Gemfile** (file)

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem "geo-distance", "~> 0.2.0"
```

**Command**

```
bundle install
```

**EDIT**

I tried to install without Bundler and it works.

```
gem install sugar-high geo_units geo-distance
```

Comment: Yes, I know bundler is a better choice, but right now I can't use it...Is there a way I can install this via gem install